# Blazor handheld barcode scanner with hidden field

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I'm working on a Blazor app that can take input from a handheld barcode scanner. (USB connected)

I already have a first draft ready, but I can't seem to get this to work with hidden input fields.
So basically, I want to catch the barcode in a hidden input field. This will be the only input field on the screen and should get the focus.
I can manage everything when the input field is visible on the screen (set focus and scan a barcode)
But as soon as I hide the input field, it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is maybe not the answer you are looking for, but it is my suggestion. Don't hide the input. I've worked on half a dozen systems with handheld barcode scanners, and every one of them allowed scanning with the barcode scanner OR entering the input manually.

There are going to be times that the barcode is damaged, and someone needs to enter it manually, or where you need to enter a barcode to the system remotely while testing or diagnosing a production issue.

Also, according to MDN, the user is specifically not supposed to edit hidden input values (I am assuming you are using input tags with a hidden type, and not a text input that is just hidden from the UI). What you are asking to do in your question, isn't supposed to work:

[*This specifically can't be edited or seen by the user via the user interface*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden#value)

Comment: That's a good remark. Is there actually another way to capture data from a barcode scanner besides using an input field?

Comment: You can try to capture keyboard key events and parse out the barcode data from the events. I've done that before. Doing that in Blazor probably requires some javascript interop, as you will need to capture the events at the page level (if you are doing it without a focusable input box on the screen). Anything more than that, and I'd have to know WHY you wanted to avoid a visible input box (which has benefits over not having one).

Comment: The application is for our plants maintenance workers. They need to register the actions they performed on a certain machine. It's intended to replace a paper version and needs to be low entry. To give them less work they need to scan a few items (badge, machine barcode, ...) I wanted to remove the boxes to avoid confusion. These are not people that are used to working with computers